# What are the greatest factors preventing the choice of a an official world auxiliary language?

Tags: languages

The potential benefits to peace, security, education, commerce, science, arts and virtually every field of human endeavor are fairly obvious. English does serve as a kind of de facto lingua franca in a number of international settings, but it is not, from what I have read, taught universally in South America, many African countries, or in parts of Asia, at least not at an early age for effective language acquisition (and I am unaware of any evidence that English is projected to take over in a reasonable period of time on its own; I have read that in Southeast Asia, for example, emphasis may even be shifting to Chinese).

Are there any particular obstacles preventing an official choice of a language to be taught alongside native languages in all the schools of the world--whether it be an endorsement of a constructed language or of a pre-existing one like English, and whether it be by the United Nations or some body with some proportionality to population?

Are there genuinely powerful vested interests who would be against such a vote?

Comment: No one likes to be forced into another culture.though only translators would have some strong interest against the vote.

Comment: Why would a global vote be "forcing" people into a culture especially when the vote was on *adding* a language they chose together?

Comment: @BrettZamir Because you can't really just add, you must substitute. There is a limited amount of time and money for education.

Comment: Because in the US any choice other than english will be rejected by ~90% of the population.  In china there are already over ~1billion that speak mandarin and they are not going to convert to English just to spite the US and will not convert to Russian for the same reason.  And Russia is not going to accept anything other than Russian.   Then there is india with over a billion people and 10 languages and no money to teach them all another...

Comment: @Chad: You realize I am talking about an auxiliary language, right? China is already very actively learning English as a 2nd (or 3rd) language, including in public schools. I also understand English is a kind of lingua franca within India at least in provinces not so attached to Hindi; obviously a world aux. language is not going to come overnight but having one could raise poorer countries' prospects (as is quite evident with participation on ODesk and the like).

Comment: But I certainly could accept the gist of your answer if it is that dumb nationalism is keeping this from becoming a reality, though I'd be interested to know if polls have been done.

Comment: @BrettZamir - It is more politics than nationalism.  We all  want to be the King and are unwilling to let anyone else be King if it is not us.

Comment: "People are dumb" is a simple answer.

Comment: This isn't even limited to languages. https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @JAB: Yes, and that might be considered a propos with languages as well, with various constructed languages competing to serve the role as IAL in some ways dividing the effort. However, a follow-up to the cartoon ought to lampoon the equally ridiculous inclination to cynically dismiss all attempts at standardization given that with agreement and willingness among the major stake-holders (at least a majority whose adoption could influence yet others), effective standardization has been demonstrably achieved. Thus, a lack of adequate traction of say Esperanto is no proof of unachievability.

Answer (score 10):

Language is a primary component of a culture. Outsourcing it to anyone is problematic at best.

This is why many countries like France have [l'Académie francaise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise), an organization dedicated to promoting the old *lingua Franca* (French).  Likewise, the [Sapir-Whorf Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) (not to be confused with [Michael Dorn](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Worf) ) posits that language not only reflects the culture, but even shapes how the world is perceived. When [Robert Greenburg](http://www.thegreatcourses.com/tgc/courses/course_detail.aspx?cid=700) suggests that the aria would only have developed in a vowel-rich Latin and the hymn in a consonantal German, he is merely extending the hypothesis.

I write these things to say that every non-English speaking culture has a vested interested in not seeing English become the dominant culture.  Already, many countries complain about American "[cultural imperialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_imperialism#American_Cultural_Imperialism:_a_gift_or_a_threat.3F)" via Hollywood is every bit as insidious as its hegemonic role as "the world's policeman."

Indeed, the driving force behind [Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto) - designed as a world language - was that no one culture would be given such power over world culture. Its creator wrote:

> "The place where I was born and spent my childhood gave direction to all my future struggles. In Białystok the inhabitants were divided into four distinct elements: Russians, Poles, Germans and Jews; each of these spoke their own language and looked on all the others as enemies. In such a town a sensitive nature feels more acutely than elsewhere the misery caused by language division and sees at every step that the diversity of languages is the first, or at least the most influential, basis for the separation of the human family into groups of enemies.

The result, of course, is what you would expect. Regimes everywhere thought the idea nonsense. Might it bring a kind of peace? Sure - because the realized it was the same kind of peace that arose from when your culture was completely killed off.  Replacing your culture with the culture of no one group in particular has proved well nigh impossible on its own - imagine if you had to agree on adopting the culture of an enemy, and you see why it just doesn't happen.

As such, the direct answer to your question of "Who would oppose English as a world language?" is anyone who wishes to preserve their own, non-English-speaking culture.  It is a pretty formidable lobby.

Put another way (and here I'm channelling @Chad, so please forgive me all)-
Russians will never accept English, French, or any language other then Russian as their national language.  If put to a vote, it would fail miserably - there is no support. Same would hold true in China, India, France, and a host of other nations.  Indeed, even in the Netherlands, where English is highly related and basically the language of business already, [Dutch News](http://www.dutchnews.nl/poll/index.php?poll_id=21&l_page=0) could only muster 51% support for such a policy in an unscientific poll.  Things would go south from there.

English is a powerful tool. Studies have shown that learning it brings about a [10% increase in wages for non-English speaking countries](http://freakonomics.com/2014/03/06/is-learning-a-foreign-language-really-worth-it-a-new-freakonomics-radio-podcast/). That is an economic motivation *for* it, and its best hope of being adopted universally.  Just don't expect anyone to like it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my question was not necessarily about English being chosen. It was about *any* language being chosen by vote. Of course if English is indeed that popular then it could be chosen, but people would be *more* capable of expressing their culture to others using such a medium, even if it couldn't translate 100% (and if a choice such as English would give a temporary "advantage" to those already speaking it). As far as Sapir-Whorf it has been discredited in at least its extreme form; non-Western people are capable of understanding science written in English papers, etc.

Comment: As far as La Academie Francaise, it is for guarding foreign words used within French, not guarding against any use of English (and many French have come over to the role of English, even while not wishing to give up their own culture). Even countries which strongly support their culture can favor a common language shared with others (as many, many individuals do by speaking in forums such as this when English is not their native language).

Comment: As far as adopting the culture of an enemy, I recall reading that native American groups which adopted English were *more* successful in preserving their cultures. Economics can indeed be powerful, but they alone don't lead to standards; standards promoters and legislation ultimately does (somewhat of a catch 22 of course, but my point is that good ideas often languish simply because of a lack of effort not merely because the conditions aren't ripe--and they won't become ripe without effort either).

Comment: @BrettZamir - How many words for snow does English have?  Chinese? [Eskimo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eskimo_words_for_snow)? (yes, it's debatable).  How about [naming blues and greens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguishing_blue_from_green_in_language). Does English have a word for the concept of [Wu wei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_wei)?  What about puns? Wordplay? Meaningful names?  It's impossible for one language to cover everything that every other language in the world covers, and without that, there will be people who will refuse to switch because something will be lost.

Comment: @Bobson: The idea is not that anyone should replace their native language. Will it cause the end of the world if the chosen international medium doesn't (currently) allow full expression of all shades of blues & greens or doesn't allow an ample expression of Vogon poetry? It shouldn't be expected to provide full fidelity because it is an *auxiliary* language, meant to supplement native language(s) and serve as a common medium. People are and have been creative enough to adapt languages to at least convey their general ideas, even it is using awkward constructions like "no-action" or what not.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should upvote or downvote the awful Star Trek pun :)

Comment: @Bobson - "Eskimo having 50 words for snow" [is a misnomer](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/263/what-are-the-nine-eskimo-words-for-snow). They simply have german-like contractions for phrases like "XXXsnow" (called "polysynthetic" language). English has 100% equivalent phrases, by merely introducing a space after "XXX".

Comment: @DVK - which is why I said it was debatable. I don't know enough about linguistics to argue it one way or the other. I knew it as an example, Wikipedia told me there was debate, so I put it in with caveat.

Comment: @BrettZamir The problem is that you are using logic to approach a problem that for many is emotional.  Logically, you are right.  But you'll never convince the vast majority of the people with logic alone.

Comment: I've up-voted your answer for the link to the fascinating poll (its intelligent phrasing as well as results) and your likely apt analysis of it. I think polls would need to be done elsewhere to really give a fair idea, but yours is I think a quite reasonable hypothesis, and your statement "Just don't expect anyone to like it" is also helpful to me as a possible indicator of why perhaps some balk at the idea of another language becoming "official" in any capacity even if they support (or tolerate) it in other capacities (like the 2nd highest answer in that same poll).

Comment: Here in China, people actually seem to accept English as a done deal for a world language, but perhaps they would, as you suggest, also balk here too if it were proposed as an "official" auxiliary language (even if of an (of course) lesser status than Mandarin).

Comment: I'm hesitant to mark yours as the answer now though because I don't agree with an *auxiliary* language being any threat to one's culture, nor am I convinced others feel the same once they understand the notion (global vote for an auxiliary language--whether it would be for English or especially Esperanto) even while I admit some may resist the notion of incorporating it into their identity by officiality.

Comment: I am also not convinced that economic motivation will alone be sufficient for it to become a fait accompli (hopefully I won't get punished by the English Academy for that one) as there has been such for a long time, just as there was a long-time economic motivation for national aux. languages before adoption actually occurred, e.g., thousands of years in China. A language is quite difficult for the masses to acquire on their own, so the opportunity cost may be too high unless taught early on in school.

Comment: Maybe the reality of increasing trade and social integration could push governments to doing it on their own, but again, there is a catch 22 situation preventing greater integration without there first being an official language.

Comment: And sorry for the spam, but even the 51% number could be interpreted as high for the Netherlands given that the concept of an official auxiliary language (beyond national languages) seems to me to be quite unfamiliar to a lot of people, and people may be hesitant to support an idea when it is just being proposed out of the blue without any previous public discourse on the matter (on the other hand I'll admit the drum of identity politics might end up lowering that number).

Comment: @BrettZamir and Affable Geek. If you must use the French definite article (it always felt odd to me, what's wrong with “the Académie française”?), note that we don't use “le” or “la” before a vowel but always “l'”.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed. Esperanto does work.  We should not overestimate the position of English. 3.7 billion people in the world do not speak it :(

I live in London and if anyone says to me “everyone speaks English” my answer is “Listen and look around you”. If people in London do not speak English then the whole question of a global language is completely open.

The promulgation of English as the world’s “lingua franca” is impractical and linguistically undemocratic. I say this as a native English speaker!

Impractical because communication should be for all and not only for an educational or political elite. That is how English is used internationally at the moment.

Undemocratic because minority languages are under attack worldwide due to the encroachment of majority ethnic languages. Even Mandarin Chinese is attempting to dominate as well. The long-term solution must be found and a non-national language, which places all ethnic languages on an equal footing is essential.

As a native English speaker, my vote is for Esperanto :)

Your readers may be interested in seeing http://uk.youtube.com/watch?v=_YHALnLV9XU   Professor Piron was a former translator with the United Nations.

Their new online course http://www.lernu.net has 125 000 hits per day and Esperanto Wikipedia enjoys 400 000 hits per day.  That can't be bad :)

Comment: Re: your London example, indeed; people complain in the U.S. about immigrants not speaking English while also maintaining it has already succeeded. I don't think it would be impractical and undemocratic, however, were there to be a global democratic vote on the issue and English were as popular as some people imagine. Some might have sour grapes about a success vote, but any language could serve the purpose and future generations would surely catch up *if* that were the majority will of the world.

Comment: If this is not the case, then a language like Esperanto might help break the impasse. I guess we really need polls to know what people would think, but it may be hard to judge since many misunderstand the whole idea itself upon hearing about it as they think it is one which aims to replace native languages, that it could only be Esperanto, or that it could only be English.

Answer (score 1):

I am one of many people who for decades have argued quietly that support for Esperanto as a lingua franca could bring many benefits to the world.

I see Esperanto as a remarkable success story. It has survived wars and revolutions and economic crises and continues to attract people to learn and speak it. Esperanto works. I've used it in speech and writing in about seventeen countries over recent years. I recommend it to anyone, as a way of making friendly local contacts in other countries. It has only been around for a little over 125 years. The major obstacle to its wider use is financial. Compared to the fortunes spent on promoting English (British Council), French Allioance Francaise) and so on, Esperanto is dependant on the efforts of volunteers within its speaker population.

Comment: I agree it could bring benefits. However, I like to point out that such a lingua franca would not necessarily need to be limited to a constructed language. In promoting the idea among Esperanto-skeptical audiences, I think it helps to promote a vote open to existing languages as well, as indeed many in at least the U.S. are very smugly defeatist in their view of Esperanto as a failure (despite the fact that financing, changing conditions, or more significantly, legislation to require it in at least some bloc or other, could possibly turn the numbers around for Esperanto).

Comment: So does your answer imply that you believe that only Esperanto could end up succeeding because of nationalism or what not (and thus financing of Esperanto is the greatest factor preventing a world aux. language)?